# how to lifecycle ignore a specific tag in auto scaling group

Tags: terraform

How the tag AmazonECSManaged is system added. I would like to ignore it in my script. but not all the tags

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "as-group" {
:
:
    tag {
        key                 = "AmazonECSManaged"
        propagate_at_launch = true
    }
    tag {
        key                 = "Name"
        propagate_at_launch = true
        value               = "wp-my-prod"
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you add more details to the question, it is hard to tell anything from what  there is in the question.